# Langchain Handle SQL Error with SQLDatabaseSequentialChain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I have an issue while using SQLDatabaseSequentialChain.
I use it with a local LLM to browse through my tables and the relations between them.

Sometimes, the generated query is not correct so the method invoke of SQLDatabaseSequentialChain return an SQL Error.
I would like to go through this error and do not stop the LLM running so it could generate an appropriate query based on the wrong one.

Is it possible ?
I did not see any params or method to do so.

I tried to check on the doc but saw nothing that can help.

This is how i call SQLDatabaseSequentialChain :

```
db_chain = SQLDatabaseSequentialChain.from_llm(llm, db)
db_chain.set_verbose(True)
question = input("Question : ")
output = db_chain.invoke(final_prompt.format(question=question))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.